# Do the mainstream C++ compiler (VC++,g++) remove calls to empty constructors/functions?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc

Let say you add an empty constructor religiously to every type in a class hierarchy. Will the compiler make a call to the function despite it being empty on object construction?

Psuedocode:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    public function Foo() {
        super();
    }
}
class Bar extends Hello {
    public function Bar() {
        super();
    }
}
class Hello {
    public function Hell() {
        prop=1;
    }
}
```

Will the call to the Bar constructor be called?

Comment: I would argue that having proper C++ code (just as simple and minimal as the pseudo-code) would have been better, and made the question easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are treated as any other C++ function. So an optimizing compiler is likely to inline them if provided in an inline form or with link-time optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

Looked at some assembly output from g++...

**g++ only called the empty constructor on -O0**

**g++ did NOT call the empty constructor on -O1 -O2 or -O3**

Basically, I compiled the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class buttered_toast {
    public:
        buttered_toast() {
            // empty constructor
        }

        void do_work() {
            printf("Actually use the class for someting...\n");
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    buttered_toast t;
    t.do_work();
    return 0;
}
```

using the following command: `g++ -O1 -S -o main_O1.s main.cpp` (replacing the "O1" with the desired optimization level)

Here's the -O0 output (it DID call the empty constructor)

```
main:
.LFB4:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
subq    $32, %rsp
movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
leaq    -1(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZN14buttered_toastC1Ev // <-- EMPTY constructor called
leaq    -1(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZN14buttered_toast7do_workEv
movl    $0, %eax
leave
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
```

Here's the -O1 output (did NOT call empty constructor)

```
main:
.LFB34:
.cfi_startproc
subq    $8, %rsp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
movl    $.LC0, %edi
call    puts        // <-- It even inlined do_work() for us, how nice!
movl    $0, %eax
addq    $8, %rsp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

*Note: I only created the function `do_work()` to help ensure that g++ didn't optimize out the whole class